# How to migrate big amount of records (4m+) to Heroku/Postgresql?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I have a csv file from MSSQL 2008 with 4million records and I would like to import that file in postgresql on heroku. I've prepared a scripts to migrate the data but it takes too long to load, I've tried to split it into multiple files but again is taking too long.

I am trying to do the import on my local pc and then push the data over to heroku but I again is not that fast.

Any ideas, suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

We recently did a large import with 30+ million records.

This is what we did.

We have setup a local copy of postgres.  We are running a rails app so we hooked this up as our development db and ran all migrations to get to the proper table structure and indexes that we were looking for.

After that, we imported our data from our MSSQL and MySQL environments that we were later going to push to Heroku.

We ran our test scripts and tested our app out to make sure all the data was valid (checking columns like dates, boolean fields, and sets)

After all the data is set, we ran a local pgdump on the data.  We used this command:

```
PGPASSWORD=your_db_password_here pg_dump -Fc --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U your_db_user_here your_db_name_here > mydb.dump
```

After that we put it on a private amazon s3 bucket so heroku can easily find it.

If you have multiple db's at Heroku or you are using the dedicated postgres instance, make sure you set your database from the command line:

```
heroku pg:promote HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_RED
```

Replace the HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_RED with yours.  You can find it with the heroku pg:info command
If you don't do this, your db will be imported to a shared instance and you will have to redo this process.

You will also need to ensure you have the pgbackups addon turned on before doing the import.  If you have not done that, do it now.

The next step is from Heroku's doc page: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pgbackups#importing_from_a_backup

```
heroku pgbackups:restore DATABASE 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/.....mydb.dump?authparameters'
```

After that you should be ready to go.  Feel free to ask questions.  This took us a bit to get figured out as the size of our data dump was over 50gigs.

Answer (score 1):

When I had a huge import like this (mine was 1 mil), I used two scripts to do it.

One broke the import into sections of 100 rows and enqueue its import into a DelayedJob task.

The second one was the script that imported it that DelayedJob ran.

Here's the batch maker:

```
def Importer.create_import_jobs(filename)
    batch_size = 100
    puts "reading csv"
    rows = []
    batch_counter = 1
    CSV.foreach(filename, :headers => true) do |row|
      rows << row
      if rows.size == batch_size
        puts "making batch #{batch_counter}"
        Delayed::Job.enqueue ImportJob.new(rows)
        rows = []
        batch_counter += 1
      end
    end   
  end
```

here's the Worker

```
class ImportJob < Struct.new(:rows)
  def perform
    rows.each do |row|
      # do you import command here.  if you want to go through ActiveRecord it would be like Employee.create(:name => row[1], :phone => row[2])
    end
  end    

  def error(job, exception)
    Airbrake.notify(exception) # for my debugging / exception purposes, not necessary
  end

end
```

Then you can run the first script to enqueue the jobs.  And then turn on workers in your heroku admin panel to eat through all the batches.  Mine took like a week, but its all dependent the speed of 1 import (mine was building indexes as it went which made each additional row import that much slower)

Note:  the workers cost $0.05 / hr.  So like a day of one worker = $1.20.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to load it to a local PostgreSQL installation and then make a dump and compress the result to upload to heroku.
Since I don't use Heroku, I don't know if you have the CLI PostgreSQL tools, if you have use them otherwise they should provide a similar way to make dumps and restores.

Check the [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/backup.html) documentation for more information about backup and restore.

Comment: Thanks that is what I am doing right now...but is taking too long.